# Return plain JSON in Spring Data Rest

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

Does anyone know a way to configure Spring Data Rest so that it returns plain JSON entities instead of HAL?

Having a Spring Boot application with Spring Data REST and MongoDB, I would like to return this:

```
[ 
  {
      "name" : "Leonid",
    "address" : {
      "city" : "My city",
      "street" : "My st.",
      "house" : 1
    }
  } 
]
```

Instead of this:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "persons" : [ {
      "name" : "Leonid",
      "address" : {
        "city" : "My city",
        "street" : "My st.",
        "house" : 1
      },
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/persons/5bba258c85c61305d4add5f1"
        },
        "person" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/persons/5bba258c85c61305d4add5f1"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/persons{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile/persons"
    }
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 1,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

I have already tried using `spring.hateoas.use-hal-as-default-json-media-type=false` and `spring.data.rest.defaultMediaType=application/json`, but neither of these properties affect the find all endpoint at all. Also, I have tried extending `RepositoryRestConfigurer` and configuring same options there, but then I started receiving such response:

```
{
  "links" : [ {
    // some stuff
  }, {
    // some stuff
  } ],
  "content" : [ {
    "name" : "Leonid",
    "address" : {
      "city" : "Saint Petersburg",
      "street" : "Zastavskay st.",
      "house" : 22,
      "content" : [ ],
      "links" : [ ]
    },
    "content" : [ ],
    "links" : [ {
    // some stuff
    }, {
    // some stuff
    } ]
  } ],
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 1,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

**UPD:**

Here's the document:

```
@Document
@Data
public class Person {
    @Id
    @JsonIgnore
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private Address address;
}
```

And repo:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository<Person, String> {
}
```

Comment: Can you please show controller and document/entity

Comment: @kj007 added an update